# Getting the smaller index for each duplicate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Let's say I have a table with two columns, one column for the ID and another for a Name. All the names in this table appear more than once.

How can I get all the IDs in the table excluding the smallest IDs for each Name?

Comment: What about Names for which there is a single value? Should those be returned or not?

Comment: The "table" is actually a query result and there are no names with single values. I specified in the question that *all* names appear *more* than once :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you could go like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM atable
EXCEPT
SELECT MIN(ID) FROM atable GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: If a given name only has one value, won't this exclude it?

Comment: Btw, all you would need to do to handle that is to add `Having Count(*) > 1` to the second query.

Comment: @Thomas: This is a good point, thanks. The OP has stated that all the names have duplicates, but if it's not the case in some other situation, your piece of advice will surely come in handy.

Comment: @Thomas: even if there are "singles", I would read the phrase "*all the IDs in the table excluding the smallest*" as "*don't get me the singles*"

Comment: @ypercube: Indeed! Although this is no more than a speculation, it is very likely that the rows to be returned are going to be sort of 'expelled', the others being left untouched. So, yes, the singles should be omitted from the result set in such case.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) using the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function for that:

```
;WITH GroupedNames AS
(
   SELECT ID, Name,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable 
)
SELECT *
FROM GroupedNames
```

This will "partition" your data by means, e.g. create groups by name, and each group will get consecutive numbers starting at 1. This way, you can easily select everything except the entry `(ID, Name)` with the smallest ID with this:

```
.....
SELECT *
FROM GroupedNames
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

and if you need to, you can even use this construct to actually **delete** all those names with a row number bigger than 1 (all the "duplicates"):

```
;WITH GroupedNames AS
(
   SELECT ID, Name,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable 
)
DELETE FROM GroupedNames
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

Comment: How does CTE's execution plan compare to EXCEPT?

Comment: @Unreason: from my non-scientific, preliminary testing with a similar query on a table I have at hand (190K rows, of which about 110K are returned), quite favorably; when I combine both queries in SSMS and look at their execution plans, my CTE takes about 35%, the EXCEPT approach about 65% of the execution time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work?

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table GROUP BY name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id
FROM yourTable a
  JOIN yourTable b
    ON a.name = b.name
    AND a.id < b.id
```

Comment: Andriy Ms answer should be much faster, simple select and exclusion on an indexed and unique field compared to distinct select of half of cross product, which i imagine would always use filesort.

Comment: @Unreason: thnx for that info. Can you test on SQL-Server about the execution plan on this query (and other ones if possible)?